# Compare string dates in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, string, date, datetime

Hi in my program i am converting the dates in string for my application purposes. I want to compare those strings to see if the dates have the appropriate difference between them. 
Example `date1 = "07/02/2015 12:12:000"` and `date2 = "08/02/2015 16:15:000"`.
 How can i compare for starters only the year value without parsing the string to date. Thanks in advance.
I have tried with `.Length` -something but with no luck at all.

Comment: *without parsing the string to date* Why the hell? Just use `DateTime`/`Date` instead of `String`.

Comment: Don't try to compare date-strings. Use `date / datetime`. There are so many date functions to compare some dates. Don't reinvent the wheel.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Convert to `DateTime` objects and then use the normal arithmetic operations to compare them.

```
dim d1 = DateTime.Parse(input1); // Use ParseExact or more control
dim d2 = DateTime.Parse(input2);
If d1.Year != d2.Year Then
  ' years do not match
End If

' or even...
If (d1 - d2).Days > 365 Then
  // more than a year apart (modulo leap years)
End If
```

*Meta comment:* I know you said "without parsing", but unless you have a really good reason (and tell us) and sensible answer will be to parse: because it is much easier and far easier to get right.

Comment: Don't reinvent the wheel when existing features within the language give you exactly what you need

Comment: Seriously i dindt know what i was thinking my head was stacked to compare it as strings for some reason.Anyhow it worked like a charm with parsing thank you all.And sorry the stupid question.